# Add element in list using Dozer without custom converter

Tags: java, mapping, dozer, data-mapping

Recently we faced the need to autogenerate mapping code.

After analysis of all bean mapping frameworks we choosed Dozer framework (it's xml mapping processor is really powerful).

But now there's a problem. We need to just add one element (client) in the end of a list. But I really don't know how to do it.

```
public class Client {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;

  // constructor, getters and setters
} 

public class OrganizationSource{
  private Client client;

  // constructor, getter and setter
}  

public class OrganizationDest {
  private List<Client> clients;

  // getter
}
```

All examples from Dozer's doc tell only about set element in list by index which is not appropriate solution when you don't know last index.

```
<field>
  <a>client</a>
  <b>clients[0]</b>
  <b-hint>Client</b-hint> // that works! it creates new element in list
</field>
```

I tried to declare custom set-method for a list (how mentioned in doc)

```
<field type="one-way">         
  <a>integerStr</a>
  <b set-method="addIntegerToList">integerList</b>
</field>
```

But to put element in list I need to call two methods (firstly *get* and then *add*) something like:

```
Client source = new Client("Source", 0);

Organization org = new Organization();
List<Client> clients = org.getClients();
clients.add(source)
```

I tried to declare set method in a manner like this:

```
<field type="one-way>
  <a>client</a>
  <b set-method="getClients().add(java.lang.Object)"</b>
</field
```

But it doesn't work.

I want to know - is there a way to do it without custom converters? And if yes -  how?